# Cannot copy files of directory into other directory

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile which should copy all dot files for me into the home directory. Unfortunately `GNUMake` does not support wildcards as used in bash and the common wildcards `$(wildcard *.c)` are limited to special file types.

My **Makefile** is:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

profile:
    @cp -r profile/ $(HOME)/

.PHONY: profile
```

Other variations I tried so far:

1. `cp -r profile/* $(HOME)` => `cp: cannot stat profile/*: No such file or directory`
2. `cp -r profile/$(wildcard *) $(HOME)` => tries to copies all files in the current directory
3. `cp -r $(wildcard profile/*) $(HOME)/` => `cp: missing destination file operand after /home/foobar`
4. `cp -r $(wildcard profile/*) $(HOME)/$(wildcard profile/*) =>`cp: missing destination file operand after /home/foobar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [The shell Function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function) using direct shell commands in makefile

```
profile:
    $shell(cp -r profile/* $(HOME)/)

.PHONY: profile
```

Otherwise set HOME variable at the beggining like this

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
HOME  := $(shell echo $HOME)
profile:
    @cp -r profile/* $(HOME)/

.PHONY: profile
```